# Join two pyspark dataframes on columns that have multiple values

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

To explain the problem better lets say that in a retail company(similar to Walmart) there are different product categories that fall under supervisors

[image]

And just assume that there is another table that indicates the profit margins of the above product categories

[image]

How can I join table 1 with table 2 on product category using pyspark considering it is a multivalued column. The original problem has more columns but that is not the concern since the only difference will be that I will be selecting additional columns but join will be based on a multivalued column.

Comment: Can you please share code that you tried that will help answer this question. You can cast Product_category column as array in first data frame and explode it and join with another data frame

Comment: check [find_in_set](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#find_in_set) and use this in join condition, `F.expr("find_in_set(....)>0")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join using a `contains` condition:

```
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed('ProductCategory', 'ProductCategory1')
result = df1.join(df2, df1.ProductCategory1.contains(df2.ProductCategory)).drop('ProductCategory1')

result.show()
+----------+---------------+-------------+
|Supervisor|ProductCategory|ProfitMargins|
+----------+---------------+-------------+
|    Joseph|    Electronics|          25%|
|    Joseph|        Kitchen|          20%|
|    Martha|       Clothing|          30%|
+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much mck. This is sleeker and easier approach but for my problem I do not want the product category twice. ofcourse I believe I can drop the extra column too. I just don't know how to do that if there is a duplicate column. Although I haven't tried yet I fear both will get dropped if use the column name to drop it.